# What are some good resources for learning binary and using PHP with binary?

Tags: binary

I want to learn to parse certain files (such as MPQ) and I need to learn binary and how to handle it with PHP. Could you guys please kindly suggest me resources for learning such things ( books, anything)?

**Edit:** I have tried unpacking the file before, but all the numbers just looks like gibberish to me and I do not know how to comprehend it and move forward.

Comment: You awarded your bounty to @Andrew, but you didn't mark his answer as accepted.  Unless you are unsatisfied, and still looking for answers, you should probably go ahead and do that. ;)

Answer (score 6):

1. The first thing you need to do before working on any binary format is to **read format specification** (eg [MPQ](http://wiki.devklog.net/index.php?title=The_MoPaQ_Archive_Format)). Because every binary format has different structure and there is no tools to read them all.
   1a. If it closed format there may be not specification at all, so you need to **reverse-engineer** it on your own. It's complicated, but you may try to read some [public course](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigmil/RevEng/).
2. Some of them are compressed, so you need to learn how to **decompress** it, in most cases, some public available compression format used and you only need to find [proper extension](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php) for your language.
3. Then you should **create structures** in your language, that matching packed structures in binary format (open file in binary mode `b` and use [pack](http://php.net/pack)/[unpack](http://php.net/unpack2.3.) functions).
4. And the last one is to **release your tools** in community, so no one needs to make the same work twice :)

Comment: I know about that, but I see all these numbers and I do not know what they all mean and what should I do with them.

Comment: You should read format specification first.  http://wiki.devklog.net/index.php?title=The_MoPaQ_Archive_Format

Comment: Thank you! I know there are wikis that give the value of certain units and what not. How do people find these? What do I need to learn to be able to do that?

Comment: Take some reverse-engineering course. It's pretty complicated. But you surely need to know assembly, how program compiled and different data-representation formats like big-/little-endian, floats/longs/ints, C-/Pascal-strings, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are opening the binary file in what is known as a "Hex Editor", you will need to understand hexadecimal. The wikipedia page is very good at explaining it, and there is a wonderful conversion chart.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

From the wikipedia page:

```
0hex    =   0dec    =   0oct        0   0   0   0   
1hex    =   1dec    =   1oct        0   0   0   1   
2hex    =   2dec    =   2oct        0   0   1   0   
3hex    =   3dec    =   3oct        0   0   1   1   
4hex    =   4dec    =   4oct        0   1   0   0   
5hex    =   5dec    =   5oct        0   1   0   1   
6hex    =   6dec    =   6oct        0   1   1   0   
7hex    =   7dec    =   7oct        0   1   1   1   
8hex    =   8dec    =   10oct       1   0   0   0   
9hex    =   9dec    =   11oct       1   0   0   1   
Ahex    =   10dec   =   12oct       1   0   1   0   
Bhex    =   11dec   =   13oct       1   0   1   1   
Chex    =   12dec   =   14oct       1   1   0   0   
Dhex    =   13dec   =   15oct       1   1   0   1   
Ehex    =   14dec   =   16oct       1   1   1   0   
Fhex    =   15dec   =   17oct       1   1   1   1
```

Comment: This is very important and the kind of things I need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to have is a Hex Editor (or Hex Viewer). If you are in Windows you can try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (with Hex plug-in) or [HexEdit](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~prewett/hexedit/). More options [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors).

Then you need to understand what [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is and how numbers are represented in binary form.

You also need to know how to read and parse a binary file in PHP. [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) method is your friend. You can read a 32-number from a binary file using the following code (taken from [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/998-parsing-a-binary-file-in-php)):

```
<?
$fp = fopen("file", "rb");
$data = fread($fp, 4); // 4 is the byte size of a whole on a 32-bit PC.
$number = unpack("i", $data);
echo $number[1]; //displays 500
?>
```